# Wie oft wird eine trennbare Vorsilbe von einem Deutschen am Ende vergessen?

Tags: separable-verb, hyphenation

Wie oft wird eine trennbare Vorsilbe von einem Deutschen am Ende vergessen?

Wie wirkt dies?

Comment: Wie kommst du denn darauf? Deutsche lassen die Vorsilbe nie.

Comment: Ähm, ich sehe an meinem Gespräch so einen Fehler...(*Ewigkeit*) ... ein. Muttersprachler begehen so einen Fehler aber m.E.n. nicht.

Comment: @Em1 Wenn ich einen Satz auf Deutsch formuliere, dann wird die Vorsilbe ab und zu vergessen, weil man z.B. schon viel in der Mitte von dem Satz überlegt. Vielleicht ist das Gewöhnungssache.

Comment: Ungefähr genauso oft, wie ein Infinitiv oder Partizip am Ende des Satzes vergessen wird, oder das konjugierte Verb am Ende des Nebensatzes - also praktisch gar nicht. Die Satzklammer (und das schließt trennbare Präfixe ein) ist etwas völlig Natürliches, wenn man sich daran gewöhnt hat.

Comment: Eine *VOR*-Silbe steht ja per Definition am Beginn eines Wortes (*vor* dem Stamm). Wie kann man sie dann *am Ende* vergessen? Oder verstehe ich deine Frage falsch? Ein paar Beispiele wären sehr hilfreich!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast trennbare Verben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich verallgemeinere die Frage mal, denn ich glaube, dass mit »einem Deutschen« wahrscheinlich »ein Mensch mit Deutsch als Muttersprache« gemeint ist. Wenn das der Fall ist, erlaube ich mir auch als Österreicher zu antworten.

---

Wenn ich die Frage richtig verstanden habe, geht es um solche Fälle (Die Klammer soll andeuten, dass das eingeklammerte Wort vom Vergessen bedroht ist):

> Ernst wird **an**rufen. - Ernst ruft (**an**).
>   Maria wird **ab**waschen. - Maria wäscht (**ab**).
>   Erwin wird **vor**gehen. - Erwin geht (**vor**).

Die Antwort ist: Das wird nie vergessen. Denn ohne den zweiten Teil des Verbs wäre die Aussage des Satz verfälscht.

Das soll aber nicht heißen, dass die Sätze ohne das eingeklammerte Wort falsch wären. Sie transportieren einfach nur eine andere Aussage.

Zu jedem trennbaren Verb gibt es auch ein gültiges und gebräuchliches Verb ohne die abspaltbare Silbe. (Jedenfalls fällt mir kein Beispiel eines trennbaren Verbs ein wo das nicht der Fall wäre.) Wesentlich dabei ist, dass im Normalfall das Verb, das ohne die abtrennbare Silbe auskommt, eine andere Bedeutung hat als das trennbare Verb.

Die folgenden Beispiele sind grammatisch völlig korrekte deutsche Sätze, aber sie bedeuten jeweils etwas anderes als die zuvor genannten Beispiele:

> Ernst wird rufen. - Ernst ruft.
>   Maria wird waschen. - Maria wäscht.
>   Erwin wird gehen. - Erwin geht.

Ich formuliere es mal anders:
Es ist möglich, aus einem Satz, der ein trennbares Verb enthält, einen anderen grammatisch korrekten Satz zu machen, indem man die abtrennbare Silbe weglässt. Das ist aber kein *Vergessen* dieser Silbe. Man drückt dadurch etwas anderes aus.

Ein Beispiel:

> Peter ruft, weil er allein in seinem Keller eingeschlossen ist, wo ihn niemand hören kann, wo aber ein Telefonapparat steht, seinen fünf Kilometer entfernt wohnenden Freund Walter **an**.

Würde man das Wort »an« am Ende *vergessen* wäre der Satz ...

> Peter ruft, weil er allein in seinem Keller eingeschlossen ist, wo ihn niemand hören kann, wo aber ein Telefonapparat steht, seinen fünf Kilometer entfernt wohnenden Freund Walter.

... zwar ebenfalls ein grammatisch völlig korrekter und stilistisch einwandfreier Satz (jedenfalls nicht schlechter als der erste Satz). Aber semantisch wäre er ziemlich unsinnig, weil es sinnlos ist, in einem Keller, aus dem kein Ton nach außen dringt, nach jemandem zu rufen, der fünf Kilometer weit weg wohnt. Noch dazu, wenn in dem Keller ein Telefon steht, mit dem Peter seinen Freund **an**rufen könnte.

Also:

- Vergessen: Nein, niemals.
- Absichtlich weglassen, weil man etwas anderes aussagen will: Ja, durchaus.
  Aber das ist dann keine Modifikation (weder beabsichtigt noch unabsichtlich) eines Satzes in dem es die abtrennbare Silbe gibt, sondern ein davon völlig unabhängiger Satz.

Comment: *frühstücken* und *vermählen* sind Beispiele für zusammengesetzte Verben, deren Stammverb keinen Sinn (mehr) ergibt. Wahrscheinlich genau deshalb sind es auch keine trennbaren Verben - Von daher dürfte deine Annahme, dass es ein trennbares Verb gäbe, dessen Stammverb alleine keinen Sinn ergibt, schon richtig sein.

Comment: @tofro: Auch »verlieren« ist ein solches Verb, das ohne »ver« heute keine Bedeutung mehr hat. Aber mir fällt ohnehin kein einziges trennbares Verb ein, dessen abtrennbare Silbe »ver« ist. (»Heinz kauft sein Auto ver.« statt »Heinz verkauft sein Auto« oder »Lisa steckt ihre Puppe ver.« statt »Lisa versteckt ihre Puppe« würde nie jemand sagen.)